# Modal window in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, vue.js, semantic-ui

I have a modal block which must be called after pressing the button.
But if the button inside the template generated page, modal window will not called.

```
    <script type="x-template" id="company-template">
<button class="ui button primary" id="addBtn">Add Form</button>
<!-- it's doesn't work on the rendered page-->
    </script>
```

If I put button outside the template, just in page. It will work.

```
    <!-- Modal Forms-->
    <div class="ui small modal" id="addCompanyForm">
        <div class="header">Добавить</div>
        <div class="content ui form">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Компания:</label>
                <input type="text" name="companyname" placeholder="название компании">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>ИНН:</label>
                <input type="text" name="inn" placeholder="ИНН компании">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="ui cancel button">Закрыть</button>
            <button class="ui approve button">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
$('#addCompanyForm')
    .modal({
        detachable: false,
        onApprove : function() {

        }
    })
    .modal('attach events', '#addBtn', 'show')
;
</script>
```

**LIBS:** jquery, semanticUI, vue

Comment: It's because the modal JS is not initialized into the vue instance.Try to put this into the `mounted()` hook - `$('#addCompanyForm')
    .modal({
        detachable: false,
        onApprove : function() {

        }
    })
    .modal('attach events', '#addBtn', 'show')
;`

Answer (score 0):

I understand, modal script doesn't know about template page element because modal script called before vue. I'm just put it after vue and it's work